# Laravel's preference on two single quotes than double quotes

Tags: php, laravel

So I got a fresh copy of Laravel on their website. Trying to wrap around my heads on how to see the default webpage that comes with it, until I figured out that it's on /public.

Now, Laravel throws me the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Error rendering view: [home.index]

syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

Upon checking the location on storage/views/some-random-hash-going-on-here, it appears that the templating language uses two pairs of single-quotes, rather than a pair of double quotes. Example: `<?php echo  HTML::style(''laravel/css/style.css'') ; ?>`, instead of `<?php echo  HTML::style("laravel/css/style.css") ; ?>`.

Checking the locally stored docs too also throws the same thing.

Is there a server setting that I can use so that PHP will just detect it as double quotes rather than single-quotes, or am I required to edit each place to match the latter code presented earlier?

I'm on WAMPServer, if that helps.

**BONUS QUESTION:** Can I just place an .htaccess file that rewrites the URL to remove the '/public' part of the URL instead of going through the hosts file?

Comment: There's nothing that I'm aware of in Laravel (3 or 4) that should give you 2 single quotes instead of a double quote.  Are you certain that the uncompiled file contains a double (or single single) quote and not two single quotes?

Comment: Yes. It was downloaded right off the bat from laravel.com, unzipped it and placed it on an app subdirectory. Not sure what you meant with "uncompiled file", though.

Comment: All blade files are compiled at run time; this is a simple process of replacing a few symbols with the equivalent PHP; `{{` for `<?php echo` for example.  I have just downloaded Laravel, looked in the home.index view and I see `{{ HTML::style('laravel/css/style.css') }}`, no problem with that line.

Comment: I see the exact same thing too on `application/views/home/index.blade.php.`. Strange.

Comment: As for your bonus question, this has been answered many times on the forums. If you can't find the answer on SO then I'd suggest making a separate question, so the answer isn't lost.

Answer (score 1):

RE: Bonus question - 
What I do is upload the contents of the public folder to the root of the site (`public_html`/`www`/`public` - varies by host) and then everything else outside of the root.  This prevents unwanted access to any of the core files.

This requires a small edit to the `index.php` file in `public`. Let's assume you're uploaded the core files to a `laravel` folder, outside the web root of your server.

If using Laravel 3, find this

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Set the core Laravel path constants.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
require '../paths.php';
```

and change those lines to:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Set the core Laravel path constants.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
require '../laravel/paths.php';
```

If using Laravel 4, find

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

and change that to

```
    require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

You should now be up and running! The .htaccess file that ships with Laravel should take care of 'pretty url' support.